# How to assign a physical name to the ECS fargate task definition using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm creating a fargate task definition like this:

`aws_ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, 'sample-task',task_role=ecs-role,cpu=1024,memory_limit_mib=4096)`

How do I assign this task definition a physical name instead of using the generated name? For example, when creating a S3 bucket we can using the `bucket_name` property, is there something similar for the fargate task definition?

Comment: Isn't the name `sample-task` in your example?

Comment: @jordanm No, `sample-task` is the id.

Comment: The `family` parameter controls the name generation. There will always be some generation due to how task definitions support revisions.

Comment: @jordanm Is there no way around it? If there isn't how can I retrieve the generated name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`family` parameter fixed the problem for me. For example:

```
aws_ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, 'sample-task',task_role=ecs-role,cpu=1024,memory_limit_mib=4096, family="sample-task")
```

Comment: This works for EC2 task definitions too, setting `family` sets the task definition name.